# Download specific Windows 10 version

Tags: windows-10

Is there any legal source where I can download a specific version of Windows 10? I have a purchased key, but for my case I need to test some hardware/software configuration specifics and I need Windows 10 version 1803. Where can I download it?

Comment: If you have a MSDN subscription, you can download just about everything Windows in all versions and variants.

Comment: It hasn’t been required to be an MSDN subscriber to download Windows in over a decade. Services like [uuldump](https://uupdump.net/known.php?q=1803) exist for 1803 ISO files. The files are most definitely legitimate

Comment: Just as a bonus, you can download Windows 10 ISOs from this tool.
https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-and-office-iso-download-tool

Answer (score 0):

The official/legitimate way:

Login to https://my.visualstudio.com/ as your MSDN licensed user. Navigate to [Windows 10](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Windows%2010) from the downloads page, and then use the 'FILTER BY PRODUCT FAMILY' list to filter for `Windows 10, version 1803`. You then have the option to download many different editions. Examples below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **unofficial** site: [TechBench](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php).

They provide links for the following Windows ISOs:

- Windows 10, Version 21H2 (build 19044.1288)
- Windows 10, Version 21H1 (build 19043.928)
- Windows 10, Version 2009 - 20H2 (build 19042.631)
- Windows 10, Version 2009 - 20H2 (build 19042.508)
- Windows 10, Version 2004 - 20H1 (build 19041.264)
- Windows 10, Version 1909 - 19H2 (build 18363.418)
- Windows 10, Version 1903 - 19H1 (build 18362.356)
- Windows 10, Version 1903 - 19H1 (build 18362.30)
- Windows 10, Version 1809 - Redstone 5 [Sept 2018] (build 17763.1)
- Windows 10, Version 1809 - Redstone 5 [Oct 2018] (build 17763.107)
- Windows 10, Version 1809 - Redstone 5 [March 2019] (build 17763.379)

While the site itself is unofficial, the last time I checked the actual download links led to files hosted on Microsoft servers and downloaded files were identical to the ones provided by MS.

Comment: I've just noticed that you're looking for version 1803 which is not available there anymore for some reason. I'll keep this answer because it may end up helpful for someone else with similar question.